# Cannot resolve symbol for all imports

Tags: android

Original Issue: Had a finalized app that I wanted to integrate Admob Ads into. I followed an online tutorial on how to do this and it broke my app. Gave me the error "Cannot resolve symbol" on all imports.

What I have tried: (In all instances I get "Cannot resolve symbol on all imports")

1. Closed app and reloaded backup copy that was working previously.
2. Started a brand new APP and copied all my saved code.
3. Even when starting completely new apps I get same error before doing any coding.
4. Invalidated/restarted cache.
5. Deleted .idea folder
6. Clean/rebuild project
7. Changed my Compile and Build Tools version
8. Uninstalled Android Studio and reinstalled
9. Uninstalled Android Studio, Java JDK, and Java.
10. Reinstalled x64 Java, Java JDK, and Android Studio and changed Environment Variables to point to jdk.
11. After finishing fresh install and starting a brand new project same issue.
12. EVERYTHING on my SDK Manager is installed minus the Android SDK Platform-tools version 22 and that is because the Android SDK Platform-tools version 23rc2 is installed. (Each time I install one the other is uninstalled)

All of these solutions I researched and found online. None of which worked. Any help or ideas? Thanks.

//Edit//

Not sure what I did but now my R. is working however I am still getting errors saying "cannot resolve symbol" for:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

Additionally, I decided to run the project and see what happens and it seems to work on the simple Hello World app that is created when you make a new project. The logcat does not report any errors. Just a lot of red squiggly lines saying "cannot resolve symbol". Any ideas?

//Edit//

I found this article:

https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/i-received-a-sudden-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-error-after-i-did-everything-exacty-on-the-video-and-tried-to-run-the-app

and it said to mouse over the imports in red and hit alt + enter. I did and it gave me an option to "Setup JDK". I did this and it cleared out all the red squiggles except for:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

So, then I hit alt + enter over this import and it says "Find Jar on web". If I click Find Jar on web it says "No libraries found for android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity"

Then, even further, if I click on clean then all the imports go back to red. Whats going on here?

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.th3ramr0d.poundforpound"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle

Comment: You need the support lib, which is setup a bit differently: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html